# Calling make_unique() and getting the data pointer in the same line gives a warning, but the same code with make_shared() does not

Tags: c++, c++17

This give a warning:

```
int main()
{
  auto num = (std::make_unique<int>()).get();
  //do something with num
  return 0;
}
```

> object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]

But the following does not give a warning:

```
auto num2 = (std::make_shared<int>()).get();
```

Shouldn't both smart pointers be destroyed at the end of the line? I'm probably not understanding something on how scoping works for `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

So, I already know that I can make the warning go away with this:

```
auto num = std::make_unique<int>();
auto num2 = num.get();
```

I still want to understand why `make_shared()` does not give a warning.

I'm using x86-64 clang 13.0.0 in godbolt.org.

Answer (score 3):

A function which returns a `shared_ptr<T>` prvalue may not be the only holder of such an object. Therefore, it *might* be reasonable to do that. The compiler doesn't know that `make_shared` will always return the only instance that manages that pointer. All it knows is that it returns a `shared_ptr<T>` by value.

The same is not true of `unique_ptr<T>`. Unless the returned `unique_ptr<T>` instance is NULL, there is no valid code where you can have a prvalue of `unique_ptr<T>` that you immediately call `get` on without that pointer becoming unusable before you could ever use it. It's all but guaranteed to be a code bug.